# ArrayOutOfBoundException while parsing a file in java froma local xml file to new text file

Tags: java, xml, parsing, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.demo.parsing.MainActivity.main(MainActivity.java:47)
```

> Writer out = new FileWriter(new File(args[0])); (line 47)

I am new to JAVA. I have been trying this code but not able to find what this `arrayoutofboundexception`. Here in this code i'm trying to parse some data from a local XML file and write it in a new file. The file is created but no text and getting the above exception

```
package com.demo.parsing;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
public class MainActivity {

//private static OutputStreamWriter out;


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream f0 = new FileInputStream("/home/kailash/workspace/paarsing/pustaka-feed.xml");

    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

        Document feed = builder.parse(f0);

        NodeList items = feed.getElementsByTagName("item");

        List<String> urls = new LinkedList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
            Element item = (Element) items.item(i);
            Element description = (Element) item.getElementsByTagName(
                    "description").item(0);
            urls.addAll(getImages(builder,    description.getTextContent()));
        }

 Writer out = new FileWriter(new File(args[0]));

        for (String url : urls) {
            out.write(url + "\n");
        }

        out.close();

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static List<String> getImages(DocumentBuilder builder, String content) throws SAXException, IOException {
    List<String> urls = new LinkedList<String>();

    for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element img :   Jsoup.parse(content).getElementsByTag("img")) {
        urls.add(img.attributes().get("src"));
    }

    return urls;
}
}
```

Comment: what is line `47` in your code? mark it as comment above please.

Comment: line 47
Writer out = new FileWriter(new File(args[0]));

Comment: you need to pass arguments while calling dude

Comment: Edit your question and mark in your post what is `line 47`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say you are newbie and dont know what ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is, Better read about [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) , as this is one the most common exception you are going to face in future.

Now about your question, it is throwing a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at line 47

As you point out , `Line 47` is

```
    Writer out = new FileWriter(new File(args[0]));
```

See the exception trace carefully

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.demo.parsing.MainActivity.main(MainActivity.java:47)
```

The trace tells you

1. the exception : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2. idex at which this exception occurs : 0
3. line that is throwing the exception : MainActivity.java : 47 (that is why i asked what is line 47)

^telling above info as you are a newbie and this description might be helpful for you in near future.

So now comming back to your statement

```
Writer out = new FileWriter(new File(args[0]));
```

`args[0]` , it represents the command line arguments (see main method definition)

are you passing any command line arguments, when you are trying to run the application ?

To pass command line arguments

Through DOS : `java nameofclassfile arg1 arg2 ......`

Through Eclipse : `right click java file -> run as-run configurations, in the dialog navigate to Arguments tab and enter your command line argument under the Program Arguments text Box  and hit run`

Comment: @KailashPawar , "DUDE" , this is not a chat, these comments are relevant to the question and to the answer, what you are doing here is spamming it. 
The question was about `arrayIndexOutOfBounds` and i suppose that must have resolved. 
if you have any other questions. Open other question. ok ?

Comment: @KailashPawar , there are `1,483,626` users on SO , `1` is you. there are many much much much more capable people interested in answering `good` questions . You should not provide links like this